# Inserting Rows in UITableView with delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a UI similar to a chat application where I need to show messages (UILabels) in the form of bubbles. I have used UITableView for this with custom cells containing a label.

Example : Lets say I have 3 messages initially.

```
Hi
How are you?
What can I do for you?
```

I want the 3 cells to appear one after another with some delay, so as to get a chat like experience.
I have tried dispatch_after and inside the block I have

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPath: withAnimation:]
```

but this inserts 3 rows all together without any delay.
Can someone please help ?

Comment: define 'doesn't seem to work'

Comment: It inserts 3 rows at the same time. And i am not able to get the chat like feel

Comment: did you try separate dispatch each adding 1 row with different delay times ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that too

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is similar like chat application which shows messages in bubble.

There are existing demos, you can download and configure easily. no need to spend time after creating from scratch.

https://github.com/tkirby/BubbleThingie

https://mobiforge.com/design-development/sms-bubble-ui-iphone-apps

https://github.com/RobinChao/ChatMessageTableViewController

Answer (score 0):

This should work but you will have to add updates and main queue.

```
[tableView beginUpdates]
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPath: withAnimation:]
[tableView endUpdates]
```

To perform actions on the main thread use

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in

 })
```

Comment: `beginUpdates / endUpdates` is not needed at all for a single `insert` / `delete` call

Comment: @Sean: Will I have to use [beginUpdates] and [endUpdates] thrice then ?

Comment: If you want to delay between, yes

Comment: Once again, `..Updates` is only needed for multiple **simultaneous** `insert / delete / move` operations. For a single operation it has no effect at all.

Comment: According to docs

// only call insert/delete/reload calls or change the editing state inside an update block.  otherwise things like row count, etc. may be invalid.

Comment: The docs says *You call this method to bracket **a series of method calls**..* aka multiple.

Answer (score 0):

You also, can insert all these rows at once and set alpha = 0 to UILabels with text.
Then you can use several consecutive [UIView animateWithDuration] to smooth set alpha to 1 - and labels will appear.

Answer (score 0):

```
   import Foundation
   import UIKit
   import QuartzCore
   import AVFoundation

 class ChatPracticeVC: UIViewController ,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

//MARK: Properties
var tableView: UITableView!
var items = [Messages]()
var names = ["item1", "item2", "item3, "item4"] // ... you can add as many names as you want
var directions = ["right", "left", "right", "right"]
let barHeight: CGFloat = 50
var timer: DispatchSourceTimer!
var continueButt:UIButton!
var showContinueButt = true

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView = UITableView(frame:CGRect.zero)
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    self.customization()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ReceiverCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "receiverCell")
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "SenderCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "senderCell")
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    let height: CGFloat = 66
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!, width: view.bounds.size.width, height: view.bounds.size.height - height - 1.0)
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    self.insertItem(index: 0)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4) { // change 2 to desired number of seconds
        self.insertTimer(i: 1)
    }
}
func insertItem(index:Int){
    self.items.append(Messages(message: (self.names[index]), position: (self.directions[index])))
    CATransaction.begin()
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    let lines = self.names[index].components(separatedBy: .newlines)
    let indexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath(row:(self.items.count - 1), section:0)
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        //you can insert animation code here on loading of cell
    }
    CATransaction.commit()
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .bottom)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
}

func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(
        deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: closure)
}

func insertTimer(i :Int){
    var index = i
    timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: .main)
    timer.schedule(deadline: .now(), repeating: .seconds(4))
    timer.setEventHandler { [weak self] in
        self?.insertItem(index: index)
        index = index.advanced(by: 1)
        if index == self?.names.endIndex {
            if(self?.names.count == 13){
                self?.continueButt.setTitle("Finish", for: .normal)
            }
            self?.timer.cancel()
            self?.showAndHideBottomBar()
        }
    }
    timer.resume()
}
//MARK: Methods
func customization() {

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = self.barHeight
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.contentInset.bottom = self.barHeight
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = self.barHeight

    continueButt = UIButton(type: .custom)
    self.view.addSubview(continueButt)

    continueButt = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:self.view.bounds.width, height:50))
    continueButt.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 185/255, blue: 210/255, alpha: 1)
    continueButt.setTitle("CONTINUE", for: .normal)
    continueButt.frame.origin = CGPoint(x:0, y:self.view.frame.size.height - continueButt.frame.size.height)
    continueButt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.continueButtClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(continueButt)
    continueButt.layer.zPosition = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
    showAndHideBottomBar()
}

//Hides current viewcontroller
@objc func dismissSelf() {
    if let navController = self.navigationController {
        navController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
}

@objc func continueButtClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    view.endEditing(true)
    showAndHideBottomBar()
    if(sender.titleLabel?.text == "Finish"){
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(FinishVC(), animated: true)
    }
    if(names.count == 4){
        let i = names.count
        names.append("item5")
        names.append("item6")
        names.append("item7")
        names.append("item8")
        directions.append("left")
        directions.append("right")
        directions.append("left")
        directions.append("right")
        self.insertTimer(i: i )
    }
    else if(names.count == 8){
        let i = names.count
        names.append("item9")
        names.append("item10")
        directions.append("right")
        directions.append("left")
        self.insertTimer(i: i )
    }
   else if(names.count == 10){
        let i = names.count
        names.append("item11")
        names.append("item12")
        names.append("item13")
        directions.append("right")
        directions.append("right")
        directions.append("left")
        self.insertTimer(i: i )
    }
}
//MARK: Delegates
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let temp:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell()
    switch self.items[indexPath.row].position {
    case "right":
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "receiverCell", for: indexPath) as! ReceiverCell
        cell.clearCellData()
        cell.profilePic.image = UIImage(named:"user.png")
        cell.message.text = self.items[indexPath.row].message
        return cell

    case "left":
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "senderCell", for: indexPath) as! SenderCell
        cell.clearCellData()
        cell.profilePic.image = UIImage(named:"user.png")
        cell.message.text = self.items[indexPath.row].message

        return cell
    default:
        return temp
    }
}
func showAndHideBottomBar() {
    if showContinueButt == false {
        self.continueButt.alpha = 0.0
        self.continueButt.isHidden = false
        self.showContinueButt = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.continueButt.alpha = 1.0
        }) { (isCompleted) in
        }
    } else{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.continueButt.alpha = 0.0
        }) { (isCompleted) in
            self.continueButt.isHidden = true
            self.showContinueButt = false
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here in i have used timer in inserting items in array, and then insert it into table view (check method insertItem and insertTimer) thus creating load delay effect
this example should mimic your chat requirements